# Improper Double integral to Proper by change of variables.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, surface-integrals

Let $D$ be the region bounded by $y = x^2, y = \frac12 x^2$ and $y = 6x$. I want to find the following
$$\iint_D \frac1y dy\ dx.$$

---

Note that $\frac 1y$ is not defined at $(0,0)$, so I apply a change of variables to convert into a proper integral. Let $x = uv$ and $y = u^2$.

Calculating the Jacobian we have $dx\ dy = 2u^2 du\ dv$. Next, I am getting confused with the limits of the integral. Need some help!

Comment: The domain $D$ is $\{(x, y): x^2/2 < y < x^2 \land y < 6 x\}$. The inequalities become
$$\frac {(u v)^2} 2 < u^2 < (u v)^2 \land u^2 < 6 u v.$$
Considering the cases $v > 0$ and $v < 0$ gives
$$(1 < v < \sqrt 2 \land 0 < u < 6 v) \lor
(-\sqrt 2 < v < -1 \land 6 v < u < 0).$$
$(u, v) \mapsto (u v, u^2)$ maps either one of the two $(u, v)$ trapezoids to $D$ bijectively, so you need to integrate over only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the integral directly as $$\int_0^6\int_{\frac{1}{2}x^2}^{x^2}\frac{1}{y}dydx+\int_6^{12}\int_{\frac{1}{2}x^2}^{6x}\frac{1}{y}dydx=6\ln(2)+\int_6^{12}\left(\ln(6x)-\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)\right)dx.$$

Comment: The first term on the rhs should be $6 \ln 2$.